# Using async to sleep in a thread without freezing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sleep, freeze

So I a label here (""). When the button (button1) is clicked, the label text turns into "Test". After 2 seconds, the text is set back into "". I made this work with a timer (which has an interval of 2000):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Test";
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "";
}
```

This works; however though, I am curious about making it work in an async method.

My code looks like this currently:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Test";
    MyAsyncMethod();
}

public async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    label1.Text = "";
}
```

This doesn't work though.

Comment: I just tried your method and it works fine, on click it changes to "Test" 2 seconds later it changes to ""

Comment: Could you expound on "This doesn't work"? What were you expecting and what did you observe? Compiler errors? Exception stack traces?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

As I mentioned your code worked fine for me, But perhaps try setting your handler to `async` and running the `Task.Delay` in there.

```
private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "Test";
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    label1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it was really difficult to tell what my problem was. However though, this seems to work without any problems :) Thank you and I'll try to word future questions more careful.

Comment: For those who do not wish to create an async function: `Task.Delay(2000).Wait();`

Comment: @JoshMc You are right, but that would cause the GUI thread to be blocked for 2 seconds. That's not a good solution.

Comment: True - only recently realized this, good point .Wait() is not preferable, for the vast majority of circumstances.