# Main process gets frozen after starting another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to write an application which transfers data between 2 systems. This application is used by a user, so it is WinForm application. When data transfering is started by a click of the user, the GUI gets frozen even though I start the data transfering in another thread. I am doing something wrong but I couldnt figure it out. here is my SIMPLIFIED code below....

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Button Click Event
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   StartThread();
}

// This starts the threaad.
public static void StartThread()
{
   string msg = string.Empty;
   int i = 0;

   continue_ = true;

   if (list != null)
   {
       while (continue_)
       {
           i++;
           Thread.Sleep(5000);

           Thread thrd1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Test());
           thrd1.Start();
       }
   }
}

// This is a simplified code.
public static void Test() 
{
        string msg = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        continue_ = true;
        while (continue_)
        {
            i++;
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            FormMain.dal.ExecuteQuery("INSERT INTO A_TEST VALUES('"+i+"')",null,CommandType.Text,out msg);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your StartThread() method includes a Thread.Sleep(5000) ... this is happening in your button click method, thus is making the UI thread sleep. Also, it looks like you have an infinite loop on the UI thread as continue_ never gets set to false

I'm guessing what you're trying to achieve here, but this may help:

```
public static void StartThread()
{
   Thread thrd1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Test());
   thrd1.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this block in `StartThread`:

```
while (continue_)
{
    i++;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    Thread thrd1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Test());
    thrd1.Start();
}
```

1. You have a while loop dependen on `continue_`, but you never change it to `false`. So you get first of all an infinite loop, which causes the GUI to freeze.
2. why you are modifying `i`, but never using it, so just remove it.
3. You don't need also `Thread.Sleep(5000);`. However, if you really want to wait a time period, you can use [an async delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878434/using-async-to-sleep-in-a-thread-without-freezing). It will give the GUI free, so that the GUI works until the delay is finished. But for this, you have to declare `StartThread` as `async`.

Answer (score -1):

In your:

```
if (list != null)
{
   while (continue_)
   {
       i++;
       Thread.Sleep(5000);

       Thread thrd1 = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Test());
       thrd1.Start();
   }
}
```

You use `Thread.Sleep(5000);`

This however still targets your main thread.
I would suggest you to remove this line.

Also, why do you use the variable 'i' while you never use it?